# How to do API calls using an array of indexes / page IDs?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Here is my code: https://github.com/d0uble-happiness/DiscogsCsvVue

App.vue

```
 <template>
   <div>
     <FileUpload @file="setFile" />
     <ParseCsvToArray v-if="file" :file="file" />
     <ProcessReleaseData />
     <FetchRelease />
   </div>
 </template>
 
 <script lang="ts">
 import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
 import FileUpload from './components/FileUpload.vue'
 import ParseCsvToArray from './components/ParseCsvToArray.vue'
 import ProcessReleaseData from './components/ProcessReleaseData.vue'
 import FetchRelease from './components/FetchRelease.vue'
 
 export default defineComponent({
   name: 'App',
   components: {
     FileUpload,
     ParseCsvToArray,
     ProcessReleaseData,
     FetchRelease
   },
   data() {
     return {
       file: null as null | File,
     }
   },
   methods: {
     setFile(file: File) {
       console.log("Received file:", file)
       this.file = file;
     }
   },
   mounted() {
     console.log("mounted");
   },
 });
 </script>
 
 <style></style>
```

ParseCsvToArray.vue

```
 <template>
   <div>
     <p v-for="row of parsedData" v-bind:key="row.id">
       {{ row }}
     </p>
   </div>
 </template>
 
 <script lang="ts">
 
 import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
 import Papa from 'papaparse';
 import ROW_NAMES from './RowNames.vue'
 
 export default defineComponent({
   name: 'ParseCsvToArray',
   props: {
     file: File
   },
   data() {
     return {
       parsedData: [] as any[],
       rowNames: ROW_NAMES
     }
   },
   methods: {
     parseCsvToArray(file: File) {
       Papa.parse(file, {
         header: false,
         complete: (results: Papa.ParseResult<any>) => {
           console.log('Parsed: ', results.data);
           this.parsedData = results.data;
         }
       });
     }
   },
   mounted() {
     if (this.file) {
       this.parseCsvToArray(this.file);
     }
   },
 });
 
 </script>
 
 <style></style>
```

FetchRelease.vue

```
 <template>
   <label>Fetch release</label>
 </template>
 
 <script lang="ts">
 import { DiscogsClient } from '@lionralfs/discogs-client';
 import ProcessReleaseData from './ProcessReleaseData.vue'
 import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
 // import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue'
 
 export default defineComponent ({
   name: 'FetchRelease',
   methods: {
     fetchRelease
   }
 });
 
 const db = new DiscogsClient().database();
 
 // const AsyncComp = defineAsyncComponent(() => {
 //   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 //     // ...load component from server
 //     resolve(/* loaded component */)
 //   })
 // })
 
 async function fetchRelease(releaseId: string): Promise<any[] | { error: string }> {
   try {
     const { data } = await db.getRelease(releaseId);
     return ProcessReleaseData(releaseId, data);
   } catch (error) {
     return {
       error: `Release with ID ${releaseId} does not exist`
     };
   }
 }
 
 </script>
 
 <style></style>
```

ProcessReleaseData.vue

```
 <template>
   <label>Process release data</label>
 </template>
 
 <script lang="ts">
 
 import { type GetReleaseResponse } from '@lionralfs/discogs-client/types/types';
 
 export default {
   name: 'ProcessReleaseData',
   methods: {
     processReleaseData
   },
   data() {
     return {
       // formattedData
     }
   },
 };
 
 function processReleaseData(releaseId: string, data: GetReleaseResponse) {
 
   const { country = 'Unknown', genres = [], styles = [], year = 'Unknown' } = data;
   const artists = data.artists?.map?.(artist => artist.name);
   const barcode = data.identifiers.filter(id => id.type === 'Barcode').map(barcode => barcode.value);
   const catno = data.labels.map(catno => catno.catno);
   const uniqueCatno = [...new Set(catno)];
   const descriptions = data.formats.map(descriptions => descriptions.descriptions);
   const format = data.formats.map(format => format.name);
   const labels = data.labels.map(label => label.name);
   const uniqueLabels = [...new Set(labels)];
   const qty = data.formats.map(format => format.qty);
   const tracklist = data.tracklist.map(track => track.title);
   // const delimiter = document.getElementById('delimiter').value || '|';
   const delimiter = '|';
   const formattedBarcode = barcode.join(delimiter);
   const formattedCatNo = uniqueCatno.join(delimiter);
   const formattedGenres = genres.join(delimiter);
   const formattedLabels = uniqueLabels.join(delimiter);
   const formattedStyles = styles.join(delimiter);
   const formattedTracklist = tracklist.join(delimiter);
   const preformattedDescriptions = descriptions.toString().replace('"', '""').replace(/,/g, ', ');
   const formattedDescriptions = '"' + preformattedDescriptions + '"';
   const formattedData: any[] = [
     releaseId,
     artists,
     format,
     qty,
     formattedDescriptions,
     formattedLabels,
     formattedCatNo,
     country,
     year,
     formattedGenres,
     formattedStyles,
     formattedBarcode,
     formattedTracklist
   ];
 
   return formattedData;
 }
 
 </script>
 
 <style></style>
```

AFAIK I want to take the `parsedData` (which will be an array of integers), and pass it on to `FetchRelease`, to do API calls using `ProcessReleaseData`.

At the moment, `return ProcessReleaseData` is throwing this error:

> Value of type 'DefineComponent<{}, {}, {}, {}, { processReleaseData: (releaseId: string, data: GetReleaseResponse) => any[]; }, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, ... 5 more ..., {}>' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?

...but VSCode's suggested fix doesn't solve it.

I was told...

> Two ways to go about this - js/ts file that is a shared “helper” or something and exports the function, or include the component, give it a ref and access function through components ref.

...but I really don't know how to do that?

I was wondering if it could possibly be something as simple as...

```
 const AsyncComp = defineAsyncComponent(() => {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     // ...load component from server
     component: import('./ProcessReleaseData.vue'),
     resolve(ProcessReleaseData)
   })
 })
```

...but that throws this error:

> Argument of type 'DefineComponent<{}, {}, {}, {}, { processReleaseData: (releaseId: string, data: GetReleaseResponse) => any[]; }, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, ... 5 more ..., {}>' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ default: never; } | PromiseLike<{ default: never; }>'.

Any help please? TIA

Edit: the project now won't compile at all, and I am now getting this:

> 14:03:49 [vite] Pre-transform error: Transform failed with 1 error: D:/MY DOCUMENTS/CODE/DISCOGS API CLIENT/DiscogsCsvVue/src/components/FetchRelease.vue:12:1: ERROR: Expected ";" but found ")"

I can't find any such error though, I am completely at a loss at this stage.

Comment: You don't have to wrap `processReleaseData` in all that Vue preamble, make it a plain function and import it accordingly.

Comment: It looks like FetchRelease and ProcessReleaseData shouldn't be components at all as you don't actually use them as components. Vue doesn't have to be used as a fancy way to write regular JS code

Comment: Sorry, I'm struggling to understand all this. Are you guys saying I should get rid of the `export default` in both FetchRelease and ProcessReleaseData, or...?

Comment: You should name the files .ts and not .vue and export the functions you want to use in other files. With no <script>, <template>, export default object and other component boilerplate things. Vue isn't an entirely new way to write apps. .vue files are just a syntax to write vue comps easier

Comment: OK, thanks. So use `export function processReleaseData` in processReleaseData.ts, is that right?

Comment: @double-happiness Looks like that, yes

Comment: OK, thanks. I've tried to create .ts versions of the function files, but that's about as far as I can get; any further assistance would be greatly appreciated, as I'm really toiling to be honest. I seem to have the key parts more or less in place, but nothing is really connected to anything else properly. Please see the GitHub repo for the most up-to-date version.